# RESTassured causing IOExceptions “existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host” in undertow

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured, undertow

I have set up `RESTassured` to run against `undertow` with my REST app in-memory using maven, which uses the `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases to set it up as a daemon and tear it down.

My big niggle is that undertow is spitting out stacktraces at the end of the integration test phases, as if RESTassured is never releasing its HTTP connections.

So my question is:

***What do I have to do to close the HTTP connections properly after each test, is it in Undertow or in RESTassured?***

Here are the gory details.

### Undertow Server

I launch Undertow with the standard Undertow code which is found all over SO:

```
    HttpHandler contextHandler = Handlers.path()
                .addPrefixPath("/", manager.start());
    return Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(port, address,
                    new GracefulShutdownHandler(contextHandler))
            .build();
```

### Stacktraces

There's one for each REST call RESTassured makes. They look like this:

```
19:07:07.569 io : Error reading request : DEBUG : XNIO-1 I/O-1 : 
    io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener  
        java.io.IOException: 
            An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:158)
    [snipped - see below for full stacktraces]
```

### RESTassured

This is what each test code block looks like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification =
            new RequestSpecBuilder()
                    .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                    .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                    .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
                    .build();
    given().spec(requestSpecification)
            .queryParam("name", "honky")
            .queryParam("description", "oh my")
            .queryParam("actualizationDate", "1999-12-31T23:59:59Z")
            .queryParam("active", "True")
            .when()
            .post("2/widget/save")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
```

### The Logs

And here are the logs below.

Undertow logging level is set to `TRACE` - I wish they output a bit more. Still refreshing though compared to *Bloatosaurus spring.io* :)

If you find yourself distracted by the two calls logged by `undertow.HttpServerExchange` in the pre-integration-test block, they seem to be fine. They are:

1. a call to see if the server is up yet (not rest-assured)
2. a rest call to create a test user (also not rest-assured)

In case anyone thinks the problem is with them, I have tested the start-up and shut-down with no tests in-between, and there are no IOExceptions, so I don't think they are causing the issue.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (pre-int-test) @ gem-widget ---
13:49:55.951 request : UT015007: Stack trace on error enabled for deployment integration-testing, please do not enable for production use : WARN : Thread-2 : io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl  
13:49:55.996 session : Setting default session timeout to 1800 : DEBUG : Thread-2 : org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger  
13:49:56.026 servlet : 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath : INFO : Thread-2 : io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl  
13:49:56.101 session : Registered session listener io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge@48b96dfa : DEBUG : Thread-2 : io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager  
13:49:56.105 servlet : Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext : INFO : Thread-2 : io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl  
13:50:13.112 servlet : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' : INFO : Thread-2 : io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl  
13:50:13.226 undertow : starting undertow server io.undertow.Undertow@5eb8dc7d : DEBUG : Thread-2 : io.undertow.Undertow  
13:50:14.378 undertow : Configuring listener with protocol HTTP for interface localhost and port 8080 : DEBUG : Thread-2 : io.undertow.Undertow  
13:50:14.424 undertow : Configuring listener with protocol HTTP for interface 0.0.0.0 and port 8090 : DEBUG : Thread-2 : io.undertow.Undertow  
13:50:14.877 request : Opened connection with /127.0.0.1:58156 : TRACE : XNIO-1 I/O-1 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener  
13:50:15.070 HttpServerExchange : Starting to write response for HttpServerExchange{ GET / request {Accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json], User-Agent=[Java/1.8.0_131], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:50:15 GMT]}} : TRACE : XNIO-1 task-1 : io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange  
13:50:15.387 HttpServerExchange : Starting to write response for HttpServerExchange{ POST /2/mgmt/create_user/TEST/true request {Accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json], User-Agent=[Java/1.8.0_131], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:50:15 GMT]}} : TRACE : XNIO-1 task-2 : io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange  
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1:integration-test (default) @ gem-widget ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.megacorp.widget.rest.WidgetSaveTests
13:50:19.928 request : Opened connection with /127.0.0.1:58170 : TRACE : XNIO-1 I/O-3 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener  
13:50:19.935 HttpServerExchange : Starting to write response for HttpServerExchange{ GET / request {Accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json], User-Agent=[Java/1.8.0_131], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:50:19 GMT]}} : TRACE : XNIO-1 task-3 : io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange  
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:8080/2/widget/save?name=THARG.YES.GOOD.IDEA.6.7.8.9&description=oh%20my&actualizationDate=1999-12-31T23%3A59%3A59Z&active=True
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   name=THARG.YES.GOOD.IDEA.6.7.8.9
                description=oh my
                actualizationDate=1999-12-31T23:59:59Z
                active=True
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
13:50:22.996 request : Opened connection with /127.0.0.1:58171 : TRACE : XNIO-1 I/O-4 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener  
13:50:23.031 transfer-encoding : No content, starting next request : TRACE : XNIO-1 I/O-4 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpTransferEncoding  
13:50:23.276 HttpServerExchange : Starting to write response for HttpServerExchange{ POST /2/widget/save request {Accept=[*/*], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Accept-Encoding=[gzip,deflate], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[0], User-Agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Date=[Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:50:23 GMT]}} : TRACE : XNIO-1 task-4 : io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange  
13:50:23.334 RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder : Parsing response as: application/json;charset=UTF-8 : DEBUG : main : io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder  
13:50:23.341 RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder : Parsed data to instance of: class org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream : DEBUG : main : io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:50:23 GMT

[

]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.974 s - in com.megacorp.widget.rest.WidgetSaveTests
13:50:24.343 io : Error reading request : DEBUG : XNIO-1 I/O-4 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener  
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:319)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:158)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:59)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:561)
13:50:24.343 io : Error reading request : DEBUG : XNIO-1 I/O-3 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener  
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:319)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:158)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:59)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:561)
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (post-int-test) @ gem-widget ---
13:50:24.749 request : Opened connection with /127.0.0.1:58182 : TRACE : XNIO-1 I/O-1 : io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener  
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1:verify (default) @ gem-widget ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.591 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-07T13:50:24+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 57M/616M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58132', transport: 'socket'
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP Can't allocate jvmti memory, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116)
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112): on getting class status [util.c:1285]
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116): Can't allocate jvmti memory [util.c:1799]
ERROR: JDWP unable to dispose of JVMTI environment: JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: the problem is with the conversion issue of the string you are passing in the url and the date type you are assuming in your code, you can easily figure it out with debugging on the test case

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong logging by mistake! I meant to show the logging where the tests pass :(